# Геометрические фигуры в css

Tags: css, css3

Шалом,вот скрин того,что мне нужно склепать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно треугольник в верхнем левом углу.Как такой создать и разместить где нужно я знаю,а вот как скруглить левый верхний угол так,чтобы при этом не появился и 4 угол,и как разместить в этом треугольнике текст да так чтобы на 45 градусов был развернут увы.**Знаю,что нельзя просить что-то сделать вместо себя,но в тырынете инфы не нашел,заранее прошу прощения**

Comment: уголок можно сделать при помощи бэкграунд градиента, а текст повернуть через transform:rotate

Comment: угол же можно скруглить у родительского блока и `overflow: hidden` ему задать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а сам текст как добавить?Если пишу его внутри дива,то он отображается после него,полагаю это из-за нулевой высоты и ширины.

Comment: Вам уже собрали ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.container {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.triangle-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: -78px;
  left: -4px;
  width: 70px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle">
    <span class="triangle-text">popular</span>
  </div>
  sdasdas
</div>
```